# How do you unlock hidden artes?

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-hd

For example, Lloyd has this hidden arte:

Lightning Thrust
Sonic Thrust used 200 times, Elemental Damage Lightning

Do you have to use Sonic Thrust 200 times with a lightning damage weapon equipped, or just 200 times and then equip a lightning weapon and then it will unlock?

If I unlock this arte, can I equip a fire weapon and then continue to use Lightning Thrust or does this arte only appear if I currently have a lightning weapon equipped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:** You can't. You don't truly unlock hidden artes. It's more like replacing an arte with a more powerful version when used, because you met certain requirements for it.

**The long answer:**

It appears the Lightning Sonic Thrust variation is a Lloyd-specific one, and it is only available if you have a weapon/item/magic that makes you lightning enhanced AND have used Sonic Thrust over 200 times. From the [Tales Wiki page on Sonic Thrust](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/Sonic_Thrust):

> In Tales of Symphonia, a Lightning-elemental property can be added to Lloyd Irving's attack through the use of the "Sardonyx" accessory, the T. Seal: Lightning arte, a Lightning-elemental weapon, or the "Purple Quartz" item, to replace the arte with the more powerful Lightning-based arte, Lightning Thrust, if Sonic Thrust has been used over 200 times. This elemental variant can be used only by Lloyd, since both Kratos Aurion and Zelos Wilder have the more powerful Lightning Blade, which has a similar effect but greater damage.

As for the criteria for using hidden techs, it seems like there are a few requirements that have to be met for any given one, falling into one of the following categories:

- Have a certain elemental effect, either by weapon/item element or elemental magic enhancement
- Be in Over Limit
- Have a specific weapon equipped
- Finish a specific quest

The most complete list I've ever found was [this Artes Guide on GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/gamecube/561316-tales-of-symphonia/faqs/31633). By searching "Hidden Techs" in the doc, you can get a list of hidden techs for various characters, and the requirements for using them. The individual character artes pages on the Tales Wiki (eg. [this page](http://aselia.wikia.com/wiki/ToS_-_Lloyd_Irving:_Artes) for Lloyd) are also a good resource for discovering hidden artes. Any tech that has requirements above and beyond using another arte a certain number of times are the ones you'd be looking for.

The requirements have to be met in order to use them. They are not permanent artes upgrades... So, for example, if you replace gear that gave you a certain element upgrade needed to use the hidden tech, you'll also use the ability to use the hidden tech.

Comment: So just because I've used Lightning Sonic Thrust before, doesn't mean that I'll always be able to use it if I don't have a lightning attribute weapon?

Comment: @ChaseC Unfortunately, yes. With these artes, it's more like you are replacing your current version with a more powerful one temporarily than you permanently unlocking a new arte (on that Artes page for Lloyd, under the requirements for 'Lightning Thrust', you can see that it's _activated_ by using Sonic Thrust while meeting the other previous requirements). See also [this answer](http://www.gamefaqs.com/gamecube/561316-tales-of-symphonia/answers/253767-how-can-i-learn-secret-techs-).

Comment: @ChaseC I actually just edited my answer a bit after re-reading your question title, because I wanted to clarify you never **truly** unlock hidden techs. More like temporarily powering them up because you met the requirements.

Comment: Beautiful. Thank you for the great answer. Now I won't waste my time trying to unlock all of these :D